# heroku [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Class 'Faker\Factory' not found

Tags: heroku, laravel-5, faker

I have problems with heroku when I do : "heroku run php artisan db:seed"

```
 $ heroku run php artisan db:seed
 Running php artisan db:seed on jaquenews... starting, run.7385 (Free)
 Running php artisan db:seed on jaquenews... connecting, run.7385 (Free)
 Running php artisan db:seed on jaquenews... up, run.7385 (Free)
 **************************************
 *     Application In Production!     *
 **************************************

 Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
 > yes
 yes

 Seeding: UsersTableSeeder

 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
 Class 'Faker\Factory' not found
```

Comment: I have tried to put the faker on require into composer.json but stil going wrong

Comment: Can you show us the `UsersTableSeeder` content ?

Answer (score 1):

When you run this command, it might tell you that the Class 'Faker\Factory' was not found. It happens because faker is required as a dev dependency. To fix this, simply open your composer.json file and move faker, from require-dev to require.
And then run composer update.

From https://dev.to/doougui/deploying-your-laravel-mysql-application-on-heroku-5d92.